# Can't remove secondary frame in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm very new at trying to learn some basic Python and TKinter.

I have written some simple code to create and populate a 2nd frame on a button press but I can't remove the frame when I'm done with it.  I can remove the frame if I use `command=edit_frame.destroy` but I want to do some other cleanup actions as well and so I am trying to use a function for it.

This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Frames test')
root.geometry('490x310')

def edit_end(frame_name,items):
# do other clean up stuff    
    btn_edit_items.config(state="normal")
    items.delete(0, 'end')
    try:
        frame_name.pack.forget
        print('destroyed')
    except:
        print('something not right')

def edit_items():
    btn_edit_items.config(state="disabled")

    edit_frame = tk.Frame(root,bg="green")
    edit_frame.grid(row=3,rowspan=7, column=2)
    edit_frame.tkraise()

    ef_items = tk.Listbox(edit_frame)
    ef_items.grid(row=2,rowspan=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)

    ef_items.insert('end', 'Item 2')
    btn_remove = tk.Button(edit_frame, text='Remove', bg='white', command=lambda: edit_end(edit_frame,ef_items))
    btn_remove.grid(row=0,column=1)


btn_edit_items = tk.Button(root, text='Edit', bg='white', command=edit_items)
btn_edit_items.grid(row=8,column=0, sticky='EW', padx=10, pady=2)

btn_exit = tk.Button(root, text='Exit', bg='white', command=exit)
btn_exit.grid(row=9,column=0)

list_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
list_frame.grid(row=4,rowspan=7,column=1)

lb_items = tk.Listbox(list_frame)
lb_items.grid(row=2,rowspan=7, column=1, padx=10, pady=2)
lb_items.insert('end', 'Item one')

# Start the main events loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `frame_name.pack.forget` doesn't call the `forget` method; you need parentheses for that: `frame_name.pack.forget()`. (Also, `forget` doesn't destroy anything, so at the very least, your comments and debugging output are misleading.)

Comment: I believe the method is `pack_forget()`, not `pack.forget()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame was added using the [`grid` geometry manager](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), rather than [`pack`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm):

```
edit_frame.grid(row=3,rowspan=7, column=2)
```

...Therefore, the [`grid_remove()`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_remove-method) method—or [`grid_forget()`](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_forget-method), depending on our needs—must be used to remove it:

```
try:
    frame_name.grid_remove()
    print('destroyed')
```

Comment: `frame_name.grid_remove()` fixed it.
A couple of dumb typos by copying from other peoples examples.